La seguridad de resorte no funciona en springboot 6
soy nuevo en framework de springboot  y estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto; y tengo fallas; hice un pequeño formulario de login personalizado pero al correr el proyecto no me lleva al login que yo hice, sino el que tiene por default el springboot, al igual hice los roles y usuarios para poder acceder y cada uno de ellos lo valide conforme al rol pero no me funciona no respeta los permisos de seguridad.
Pondre el mi codigo:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig{

@Bean  
static BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}


protected SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    //try {
        http
        .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
        .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth.requestMatchers("/", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/listar").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/ver/**").hasRole("USER")
        .requestMatchers("/uploads/**").hasRole("USER")
        .requestMatchers("/form/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .requestMatchers("/eliminar/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .requestMatchers("/factura/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .formLogin(form -> form
                .loginPage("/login_home")
                .permitAll()
            );
        
    //} catch (Exception e) {
    //  e.printStackTrace();
    //}
     return http.build();
}

@Autowired
public void configurerGoblal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception{
    
    PasswordEncoder encoder = passwordEncoder();
    UserBuilder users = User.builder().passwordEncoder(encoder::encode);
    
    builder.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(users.username("admin").password("12345").roles("ADMIN", "USER"))
    .withUser(users.username("usr").password("12345").roles("USER"));
}

}
estuve investigando un poco que hay código de sprinboot que son obsoletas pero la cuestión es que no me arroja ningún error al igual no me funciona, es como si no le indicara nada.
al igual inserto la dependencias de pom.
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

agregare su controlador:
 @Controller
 public class LoginController {

@GetMapping("/login")
public String login(Model model, Principal principal, RedirectAttributes flash) {
    
    if (principal != null) {
        flash.addFlashAttribute("info", "Ya ha iniciado sesion anteriormente");
        return "redirect:/";
    }
    return "login";
 }
}

no se en que estoy fallando o que me falta para hacer que me funcione????
